# Creating a Twitter-like timeline using loops, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter

At the moment I have Fans that can follow Artists. Now I want to display Artist's microposts of the Artists the Fan is following.

I want to sort Artist's microposts by `created_at` as they are created.

```
<% @fan.artists.each do |artist| %>
  <% artist.artist_microposts.sort_by{ |micropost| micropost.created_at }.each do |micropost| %>
   <%= micropost.content %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's sorting by `created_at`, but since it's looping through each artist first, it's displaying all microposts that belong to one artist, then displaying all mircoposts that belong to the next artist, and so on.

I want it to be more of a timeline, like Twitter, that displays microposts at they come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a join table between `fans`, `artists`, and `artist_microposts`. I then did

```
<% @fan.artist_microposts.sort_by{ |micropost| micropost.id }.each do |micropost| %>
   <%= micropost.content %>
<% end %>
```

Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you implement this feature. If you want to update the timeline as new tweets arrive, then you need to listen to changes using Jquery. Watch this [http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes][1]
It will show you how to implement the feature you are looking for.

Hint : Don't sort by created_at, it's a bad practice, because create_at is not an index and will be slower. Instead sort by id, it's auto incremented and indexed.

```
artist.artist_microposts.order('id DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solving by first fetching the *artist ids* and then selecting the posts that was associated with those artists.

```
irb(main):019:0> fan = Fan.first
#<Fan id: 1, name: "Tony">

irb(main):020:0> ids = fan.artists.pluck(:id)
#=> [1, 2]

irb(main):022:0> posts = Post.where(:artist_id => ids).order("created_at DESC")
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
 #<Post id: 3, text: "Third Post", artist_id: 1, created_at: "2015-02-10 12:54:32">, 
 #<Post id: 2, text: "Second Post", artist_id: 2, created_at: "2015-02-09 12:53:14">, 
 #<Post id: 1, text: "First Post", artist_id: 1, created_at: "2015-02-08 12:52:51">  ]>
```